# SharePoint 2013 Root Web Application No Website

Tags: web-application

On our SharePoint 2013 Root Web Application we dont appear to have a website, instead receiving a 404 not found error.

Our root site is: http://teams.ourdomain.local

We have site collections running from this perfectly. 
For exmaple http://teams.ourdomain.local/Resources/IT

We have the following Managed Paths setup:

sites (Wildcard Inclusion) - not currently being used
(root) (Wildcard Inclusion)

Any help with getting this sorted would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create a Root Site Collection (at "/") via Central Administration/PowerShell. It is not supported to run without a Root Site Collection on a Web Application.

Comment: Right, but you need to create a Site Collection at that FQDN (the Path will be "/" when you go to create the Site Collection for that Web Application).

Comment: If we already have a top-level domain of teams.ourdomain.local Does that mean that we have to then create a Site Collection called "teams" using the root "/" managed path? and then would it be best to change the name of the web application as otherwise it would read: teams.ourdomain.local/teams/resources/it Ideally we want it to be teams.ourdomain.local/resources/it We have already created sub-sites and populated with data and using these sub sites. So need a fairly easy way to get this sorted.

Comment: No. In CA, go to Application Management -> Create site collections. Select the Web Application in the dropdown. Give the Site Collection a name. The "URL" will be http://teams.outdomain.local and in the dropdown, it will simply be "/". Select your template and one or two Site Collection Admins, then create it. You do not have to use this site, it just must exist.

Comment: Hello Trevor! Do you have a reference which confirms your statement "It is not supported to run without a Root Site Collection on a Web Application.". I have a problem which only exists if Root-SC is missing and developers say it must work that way.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2590564